# What is naming standard for creating object?

Tags: c#, camelcasing

As per coding standard object name for class is
eg  `SqlConnection sqlConnection=new SqlConnection();`

but when we have class like `IPAddress` (first 2 char are capital), what will be name of object?

```
IPAddress iPAddress=new IPAddress();
IPAddress ipAddress=new IPAddress();
IPAddress IPAddress=new IPAddress();
```

What is best way according to standard.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use meaningful names to instances of objects.
Start with lower case letters and follow with upper case.

For example:

```
IPAddress ipHome = new IPAddress();
IPAddress ipWork = new IPAddress();
IPAddress ipGirlFirend =new IPAddress();
```

or

```
IPAddress ipAdressHome = new IPAddress();
IPAddress ipAdressWork = new IPAddress();
IPAddress ipAdressGirlFirend =new IPAddress();
```

**The standard is the rule that you choose to follow in your development according to those who work with you.**

This could be interesting
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Answer (score 2):

I don't like `iPAddress`. Looks like `PAddress` is the name of something and that `i` is just a prefix for that.

I don't like `IPAddress`. Looks like a type name.

I do like `ipAddress`. Easy to read. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Naming conventions are just that, e.g. conventions and not rules. However, Microsoft have some [design guidelines for developing class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042(v=vs.100).aspx) and among those conventions are [capitalization conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).

In your case *IP* is an acronym and because it contains only two letters it is considered a *short* acronym. The naming rules for short acronymes are

> Do capitalize both characters of two-character acronyms, except the first word of a camel-cased identifier.

So the type should be named `IPAddress` and if you decide to create a variable with the same name it should be `ipAddress`.

Note that these are guidelines that Microsoft tries to (and also sometimes fails to) follow when creating the .NET base class library. You do not have to follow these guidelines but doing that will make your code consistent with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

You can name the objects with something more meaningful like:

```
IPAddress IPAddressAccountingDept = new IPAddress();
```

and so on. It's all your choice.The compiler doesn't care how they are named as long as they do not clash with keywords etc.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in postfixing variables with a number as types and variables have different symbol namespaces. You might aswell name it `IPAddress`.

Comment: Please explain further.

Comment: -1 for suggesting postfixing with a number (unless this was ironic...). Variables should be given _meaningful_ names. If you find yourself numbering your variables, maybe you should have used an array. Your second suggestion - while long-winded - is useful.

Comment: lol. @AAT Noted and corrected.

Comment: OK downvote reversed!

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no standard for naming. People vouch for Hungarian notation, but its outdated and tedious and a little bit confusing. The only rule is that you should know its purpose on seeing the variable even after a long time. It should be maintainable and understandable to other people referring your code.

That said, the one Daniele proposed is the best you could use in this situation.
And sure camelCasing is more readable for variables. 
pascal for ClassNames or others things in the global scope.